# Sorting The ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I Have 3 ArrayLists for example `list1`,`list2` and `list3`

```
list1={ram,kevin,sachin,akshay,salman};
list2={111111111,22222222,3333333333,4444444444,5555555555};
list3={ram@gmail.com,kevin@gmail.com,sachin@gmail.com,akshay@gmail.com,salman@gmail.com};
```

i want to sort `list1` in alphabetical order and i need other list to sort according to `list1`.

Comment: Use POJO for these 3 attributes. It seems name, email, id

Comment: Why don't you have _one_ list containing custom elements that have those 3 attributes?

Answer (score 2):

Sorting one list and updating others according to that sort order is quite cumbersome, since you'd have to match the new index of an element to the old index and use both to update the other lists.

In some cases that would be necessary and I'd solve that with some intermediate maps but in most cases, yours included, I'd just create an object for the data and put them into a single list, e.g.:

```
class User {
  String name;
  int id;
  String email;
}

List<User> list = ...;

Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<User>() {
  public int compare( User lhs, User rhs ) {
    return lhs.name.compareTo(rhs.name); 
  }
});
```

Note that I intentionally left out stuff like constructors or null checks, to boil the code down to the essential parts.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to do something like so (as per the recommendations above):

```
public class User implements Comparable<User>
{
    private String name;
    private String ID;
    private String email;

    public int compare(User u1)
    {
         return this.getName().compareTo(u1.getName());
    }
}

...

List<User> users = ...
Collections.sort(users);
```

The above code should sort the elements in [Lexicographical Order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) by taking the `name` as sorting parameter.

Comment: `implements Comparator` I guess you mean `implements Comparable` and thus `public int compareTo( User other )`.

Comment: @Thomas: Yes you are correct. Change made thanks :)

Comment: @Keppil: Yes you are correct. Change made thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Comparator`. There you define what to compare and how, in the `compare()` method you define what should be returned from two of your instances. Here's an example for a `String` `Comparator`.

```
new Comparator<String>() {
  public int compare(final String user1, final String user2) {
    // This would return the ASCII representation of the first character of each string
    return (int) user2.charAt(0) - (int) user1.charAt(0);
  };
};
```